# Pairing a "Tile Mate" to MacBook Pro / OSX 10.10 directly

Tags: macos, bluetooth

**NOTE: I don't want to use the "Tile" app. I want a connection directly to my MacBook.**

I would like the Tile Mate to appear in the Bluetooth devices menu (System Preferences > Bluetooth > Devices). **Is this possible? If so, how do I go about it?**

Using:
 - "Bluetooth Explorer" Version 4.3.0 (4.3.0f10)
 - "Hardware IO Tools" Version 6.3 for XCode

I'm able to detect the Tile using:

Bluetooth Explorer> Low Energy Devices > Start Scanning

However I'm not able to see the device in the normal Bluetooth pairing dialogue ( System Preferences > Bluetooth )

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to edit your question to include the exact model of MacBook Pro you're referring to? Also, it'd be good if you could actually clarify what you're asking? As it's currently written there's no question, and you also mention that you will update the question as you progress, so it's not clear what you're asking of us?

Comment: If this question weren't on hold, I'd post an answer: Bluetooth Low Energy devices aren't paired with the same way as traditional Bluetooth devices. Any program (which can be something you write or a tool like Bluetooth Explorer) can interact with it. If you need more info, share what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: @Monomeeth the title is exactly what Im trying to do.  I was using stack overflow temporarily as a store for the process I was going through as my text editor was continually crashing during this process.

Comment: @sy4 Noted.  Im trying to figure out if the hardware of the tile is locked down in a way that its not detectable / pairable like a normal device.  IE "is the hardware locked down?"

Comment: "You won't be able to find BLE devices in your Bluetooth device search." per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24163808/pair-macbook-with-sensor-device-over-bluetooth-le

Comment: The [tile mate](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/news/teardown-tuesday-bluetooth-trackers/) has a [BLE-only chip](https://www.dialog-semiconductor.com/products/connectivity/bluetooth-low-energy/smartbond-da14580), it doesn't support bluetooth pairing. I think you're confusing two things here–tile lets you "pair(1)" a tile to your account, and bluetooth classic lets you "pair(2)" two devices that support it. You're trying to pair(2) a tile that doesn't support that type of pairing.

Comment: Id like my laptop to lock when the Tile gets too far from it ... is that possible to do ?

Comment: It should be possible to program that, so someone may well have. I'm not aware of any software to do that, however, and I'm quite sure it's not built directly into the OS, so you'll have to search.